# How to customize BsGridView to show links instead of BsButtonColumn?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii-extensions

Given the code below, I need to customize the **third** column to show **two links** instead of that `BsButtonColumn`. I didn't find any related documentation to get the answer.

```
<?php
    $this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.BsGridView',
        array(
            'id' => 'activity-translation-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
            'filter' => $model,
            'columns' => array(
                'id',
                'name',
                array(
                    'class' => 'BsButtonColumn',
                ),
            ),
        )
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
$this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.BsGridView',
    array(
        'id' => 'activity-translation-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
            'id',
            'name',
            array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.BsButtonColumn',
                'template' => '{en} {es} {it}',
                'buttons' => array(
                    'en' => array(
                        'label' => 'EN',
                        'url' => '"translate/en/" . $data->id',
                        'visible' => '1',
                    ),
                    'es' => array(
                        'label' => 'ES',
                        'url' => '"translate/en/" . $data->id',
                        'visible' => '1',
                    ),
                    'it' => array(
                        'label' => 'IT',
                        'url' => '"translate/it/" . $data->id',
                        'visible' => '1',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, @AivarLuist! It worked. I just didn't understand how `$data->id` is evaluated inside simple quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.BsGridView',
    array(
        'id' => 'activity-translation-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
            'id',
            'name',
            array(
                'class' => 'CLinkColumn',
                'urlExpression' => '"translate/en/" . $data->id',
            ),
            array(
                'class' => 'CLinkColumn',
                'urlExpression' => '"translate/es/" . $data->id',
            ),
            array(
                'class' => 'CLinkColumn',
                'urlExpression' => '"translate/it/" . $data->id',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: If someone knows how I can use only one column to render three links, instead of using three columns, I will accept it as the right answer.